# Bad permissions after uploading file to PHP server

Tags: php

I'm running the following code on a file that has been uploaded to this page through a POST.

```
$newname = "images/".$name.".".pathinfo($_FILES["file"]["name"], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);   

//Copy the file from its temporary location to its real location.
if (file_exists("images/".$name))
    throw new Exception("images/".$name." already exists.");

move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $newname);
echo "Stored in: ".$newname."<BR />";
```

The file shows up in the correct location on the web server, and it's the correct size.  When I try to view it though it says "... you don't have the correct permission to access the file location."

I'm running on Windows 7 testing this on a local Apache web server, and all files for this site are in the same folder (except the uploaded images are held in the /images folder within that folder, but I switched that back and forth and it didn't help).

What am I doing wrong and how can I stop this permissions problem so I can view the files right after upload?

**EDIT**

I can access the file if I raise my permissions to administrator and give the file a permissions set for normal users.

I have tried using chmod as suggested in the answer below to change the permissions for all users once the file is uploaded, but that doesn't seem to work.

This isn't a tremendous issue because the web server can still use the images which is what I really need - but I'd like to be able to view them without administrator privileges to simplify my test environment a little bit.  So any further suggestions are greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Where are you storing the files? Could be that you don't have administrator privileges.

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned that.  It's my home laptop, and I have the only account and it's an administrator account. The files are stored in a folder within my apache web server root.

Comment: And how exactly you are accessing those files? It doesn't matter if your account is administrators, because windows runs as non-administrator by default, and, when those privileges are needed, your are prompted to grant them. (remebmer those modal windows with Yes - No choice when running some executables?)

Comment: Okay, I edited the question with some new info after following up on your comments.

Comment: btw, chomd works on unix systems, not windows (not completely, atleast).

Comment: Ah kk, I'm mainly a UNIX programmer but I use windows at home - I had figured that chmod in PHP was multiplatform and just took the name from unix.  Guess that was wrong :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try running:

```
echo(fileperms($newname));
```

To get the octal value of the files chmod settings after it is uploaded e.g. `0755`

If they are set too low you can use:

```
chmod($newname, 0755);
```

To set them to something which will allow you to view them.

Comment: Oh well, I got around it and this was the best answer, so enjoy ;)